# How to resolve "Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'number'" kind of error

Tags: typescript

I have a typescript project which was working fine some years back. I must have done some updates to my system meanwhile.
I recently returned to it and while building it I am running into errors of kind :

```
"Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type '$some_type$'".
```

I understand that I can go and do proper casting in all these assignments. However I wish to know what might have broken this and is there a configuration setting I can do so as to make it work as it is ?

My config file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",   /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */
        "module": "amd",
        "allowJs": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node", 
        "outDir": "out", 
        "sourceMap": true, 
        "baseUrl": "./src", 
        "strict": false,
        "strictNullChecks": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "typeRoots": [
            "./node_modules/@types"
        ],
    
        "paths": { 
            "%COMMON/*": [ 
                "../../common/*" 
            ]
        }
    },
    "include": [ 
        "src/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [ 
        "node_modules", 
        "**/*.spec.ts"
    ],
    "lib": [ 
        "es2016",
        "dom",
        "es5"
    ]
}
```

An example error:

I had a statement:

```
let texName: string = obj["texture"];
```

I had this working perfectly some years back. However now, I have to provide proper cast

```
let texName: string = <string>obj["texture"]
```

`obj` is passed as a parameter of type `Object`. An instance would be something like

```
export class LeafNode  {

   
    protected meshName: string;
    
    protected material: Material;

    protected textureName: string;

    protected numIndicesToDraw: number;
    protected textureMatrix: mat4;
    protected eps: number = 0.000001;

    /* Some methods */
}
```

Comment: Please make sure that you are providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Currently there is no way for us to answer this question

Comment: This is not a code question. As I said, I must have made changes to various modules in my system and I am trying to figure out what might have caused this to break. I understand I cannot have a straight answer to this. I am looking for educated guesses from community.

Comment: as the error says, `$some_type$` has a type, which is not a supertype of `unknown`. For example, `number` is a supertype for any literal number: `let num: number = 1` and you can do this: `let a: unknown = 1`, but not let b: number = {} as unknown`. Does this answer your question? If yes I'll write an answer explaining; otherwise, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks. As an example, I had a statement: ```let texName: string = obj["texture"];``` I had this working perfectly some years back. However now, I have to provide proper cast ```let texName: string = <string>obj["texture"];``` I can go and do such casts at  all the places I am getting similar errors, but I am also looking for the reason. Was there a recent update which mandates that we supply the type explicitly ? And is there a way around, say by providing some compiler option so as to not raise this error.

Comment: What is the type of `obj`?

Comment: obj is of type Object. Sorry for missing that.

Comment: I believe it's because either `strict` or `noImplicitAny` tsconfig option was enabled. For example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strict=false&noImplicitAny=false#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArAXDA8kgpsWBeGA3gLABQMMUmAHlAK4BOmqA5NPQJZgDmzANKQF8A3KVIAbTLACGqNpy4x8CRAG1mlGg0zMAuiJJA) there is no error, since the options mentioned are not enabled

Comment: Didn't enable them. Also tried disabling those explicitly. Still didn't help. I will add my config file to the question.

Comment: Please include the definition of `obj`

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to provide code, for better answer, but it is mainly of type incompatibility